# How to find a file with pattern of file that have almost the same name UNIX KSH

Tags: shell, unix, find, sh

I'm trying to find a file with a specific pattern but files have almost the same name, unique difference is a number but is is displaying both of them.

```
example:

/home/user/file_201024.txt
/home/user/file_201025.txt
/home/user/file2_401023.txt

command:
find /home/file*txt -mtime -1 -exec ls -l {} ;

Result:
/home/user/file_201024.txt
/home/user/file_201025.txt
/home/user/file2_401023.txt
```

I just want all the files that have file*.txt but not file2*.txt, do you know how can I avoid to get file2*.txt and just get file*.txt

Comment: You'll need to provide some more examples as I'm guessing the obvious solution ... find /home/file.txt ... isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: Be careful when globbing from the find command that you don't have the shell expand it first.

find /home -name "file.txt"

Comment: I just edited my question, maybe it was not clear... @markp

Comment: Well, what I have to do was...
`find /home/file*txt -mtime -1 -exec ls -l {} ; | grep -v "file2"` not sure if exist another solution... but at least this works...

Comment: Again, some obvious solutions based on the limited example set: find /home -name file[_]*.txt ; find /home -name file[^2]*.txt

Comment: awesome, it is working with file[^2]*.txt but not with file[_]*.txt, is not displaying anything... @markp

Comment: Per bryan's comments, wrap the search pattern in double quotes and see if that helps; run  your searches from /home and you'll see what bryan's talking about re: globbing and needing to wrap search pattern in quotes. [fwiw, I'm getting matches in solaris/ksh93, linux/ksh93 and cygwin/mksh]

Answer (score 1):

With below command we can get files without file2*.txt

```
 find /home -iname file_*.txt
```

or

```
find /home -iname file_*txt
```